# How to modify intervals on matplotlib's qualitative color maps?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, visualization, colorbar

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

---

I have a 2D numpy array:

```
mock=\
np.array([[0.1,0.2,0.3],
          [0.2,0.3,0.4],
          [0.3,0.4,0.5],
          [0.4,0.5,0.6],
          [0.5,0.6,0.7],
          [0.6,0.7,0.8],
          [0.7,0.8,0.9]])
```

I plot these values using the `tab20c` colormap, from the so-called "Qualitative" colormaps:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
im = plt.imshow(mock,cmap = "tab20c", vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.colorbar(im)
```

[image]

How would I go about this if I wanted all the values below a certain value, let's say 0.25 having the same color as 0.25 has, replacing not only the colors in the plot itself, but also in the colorbar? The expected output would be then: all 3 squares in the top left corner to be red, bottom 5 rectangles in the colormap are also all red.

By doing this, I am essentially modifying the interval for the color red in the barchart: instead of showing values in the interval between 0.2 and 0.25 as red, the new version will show everything in the interval between 0 and 0.25 red.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adapt an existing colourmap:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap

tab20c = cm.get_cmap('tab20c', 256)
newcolors = tab20c(np.linspace(0, 1, 256))
red = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1])
newcolors[:int(256/4), :] = red
newcmp = ListedColormap(newcolors)


mock=\
np.array([[0.1,0.2,0.3],
          [0.2,0.3,0.4],
          [0.3,0.4,0.5],
          [0.4,0.5,0.6],
          [0.5,0.6,0.7],
          [0.6,0.7,0.8],
          [0.7,0.8,0.9]])


plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
im = plt.imshow(mock,cmap = newcmp, vmin=0.0, vmax=1)
plt.colorbar(im)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, you should maybe explicit the calculation of `256/4` from the actual data ;)

Answer (score 3):

What about using [`numpy.clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) to set the data below 0.25 to 0.25?

```
im = plt.imshow(np.clip(mock, 0.25, np.inf), cmap = "tab20c", vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

This seems to be the most straightforward solution to me as it doesn't require to mess with the plotting parameters.

output:

[image: clipped data]

Comment: Nice solution, though the colorbar colors did not change, while @Hiibb's solution does change that as well. +1

Comment: @zabop yes, I only saw this requirement afterwards ;) You could get the vmin to 0.25 in my case (but this would change the colorbar scale)