# How to specify color of extension triangle when using ListedColormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, data-visualization, colorbar

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71033762/8565438) provides an example of how to use `ListedColormap` to create a colormap.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap

tab20c = cm.get_cmap('tab20c', 256)
newcolors = tab20c(np.linspace(0, 1, 256))
newcmp = ListedColormap(newcolors)
```

I know I could just use the `tab20c` color map and not `ListedColormap` in this particular case shown here, but the more complicated example discussed in that answer requires `ListedColormap`. I avoid that complication because it is not the focus of this question. Use `newcmp` to plot a function:

```
mock=\
np.array([[0.1,0.2,0.3],
          [0.2,0.3,0.4],
          [0.3,0.4,0.5],
          [0.4,0.5,0.6],
          [0.5,0.6,0.7],
          [0.6,0.7,0.8],
          [0.7,0.8,0.9]])
         
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
im = plt.imshow(mock,cmap = newcmp, vmin=0.0, vmax=1)
plt.colorbar(im,extend='min')
```

[image]

I could use the `extend='min'` kwarg in the `colorbar` call to extend the colorbar downwards.

I would like to modify the color of this triangle at the bottom of color bar. To make it, let's say, yellow, I tried the above code with `tab20c = cm.get_cmap('tab20c', 256).with_extremes(under='yellow')`, but the triangle remains blue. I have read about `.with_extremes()` [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html).

---

### Question

Without changing the rest, **how can set the color of the triangle below the colorbar?**

---

I hope there is a solution involving these 3 lines:

```
tab20c = cm.get_cmap('tab20c', 256)
newcolors = tab20c(np.linspace(0, 1, 256))
newcmp = ListedColormap(newcolors)
```

as they are important in customizing the colorbar for more complicated cases then presented here.

Comment: By default, you get the lowest color.  You can use `newcmp.set_under('purple')` (`with_extremes` should also work).  But note that the colorbar is generated from the colormap used for the image (it's the first parameter to `colorbar()`).  If you want a different colormap for the image and the colorbar, you need to create a dummy `ScalarMappable` using that new colormap and the norm from the image for the colorbar.  Can you confirm you want the colorbar "under" color to be different from the one used for the `imshow`?

Comment: @JohanC thank you for the comments. Yes, I'd like it to be different.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer uses the same colormap for both.  (A difference between `set_under` and `with_extremes` is that `set_under`changes the given colormap, while `with_extremes`  creates a new colormap, so you'll need to assign the result to a new variable.)

Comment: Thank you @JohanC. If you would like to add these insights as an answer, I think it'd be useful for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for the [`.set_under()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_under) method. For example:

```py
tab20c = cm.get_cmap('tab20c', 256)
newcolors = tab20c(np.linspace(0, 1, 256))
newcmp = ListedColormap(newcolors)
newcmp.set_under('k')
```

would lead to this image:
[image]